# How to install kubernetes using kubeadm on a host walready running docker multi container application

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, iptables, firewalld

I'm trying to install kubernetes on one of my centos host using kubeadm. But in the same host, there is already running microservices multicontainer application. When i enable the firewalld service while installing kubernetes to allow the ips which are required to the kubernetes, my docker multicontaier application is flushing off its connections. Could anyone please help me to install kubernetes on the same host while my docker application running smooth ? I've tried sequentially starting the applications such as starting docker demon after the firewalld and vice versa but it also not working.

Comment: Not sure it is a good idea: kubernetes expect to be alone. Could you switch your docker multicontainer application to kubernetes ? Another way is to use namespace in containerd, but it is going to require some works.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this by switching off the firewalld and letting kubern8s to choose its own ports.